# msvs2010 why can't I change name property for control using MFC dialog editor?

Tags: visual-studio

This is stupid.  I've done this a hundred times before but seems that I am either in the "wrong" spot or the IDE has to be in a particular state, or maybe the IDE has changed since I've used it last (used a very old version prior).

So I select the control in the dialog editor and the properties show up like so:

[image: properties docked control]

Just in case I was mistaken I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492140(v=vs.100).aspx) article which states that I'm supposed to be able to just type in the name in the properties box.  However as you can see it is greyed out and non-editable.

Is there some other location that I'm missing?

**NOTE:** Although the link shows `Visual Basic and Visual C# Tutorials` up the navigation tree, I recall that this was similar for C++ as well.  I can't seem to find any info for the C++ environment (which should be the same as it uses the same IDE).

Comment: So there is no one who has any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

I always had knew that field having edition blocked. When I wanted to change I had to go to the ID entry instead of Name.